# Are there ways to make low degree checks for enumerative formulas except for curves in  CP^2? 

Tags: singularity-theory, gromov-witten-theory, enumerative-geometry

This is a concrete question in Enumerative geometry. Let $S$ be a compact 
complex surface and $L\rightarrow S$ a holomorphic line bundle. Let

$$ \delta_d = \text{dim}~  \mathbb{P}(H^0(S,L^d)) $$

i.e the dimension of the space of degree $d$ curves, up to scaling. 
Define $N^d(m,\chi_k)$ to be the number of degree $d$ curves that pass 
through $\delta_d-(m+k)$ points and have $m$ distinct simple nodes 
and one singularity of type $\chi_k$, where $\chi_k$ is a singularity 
of co dimension $k$. For example you can take $\chi_k$ to be $A_k$, $D_k$ 
or $E_k$ singularity. My question is the following. Aside from the case 
of $S= \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ and $L= \gamma^{*}$, can you give some other 
examples where I can make some low degree checks? Let me give a few examples 
to illustarte what I mean in the case of $S= \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ and

$L= \gamma^{*}$.

Let us consider the number $N^d(0,A_1)$, the number of degree $d$ 
curves passing through $\delta_d-1$ points and having one simple node. I 
claim that the answer is $3(d-1)^2$. There are three instances where I 
can actually check this. For $d=1$, I am asking how many lines are 
there through one point that has a node. Clearly zero. For $d=2$, I 
am asking how many pair of lines are there through $4$ points. That is 
$3$. And for $d=3$, I am asking how many genus zero cubics are there through 
$8$ points, which can be obtained through Kontseviche's recursion formula
(i.e 12). There are several other examples I can give.  If it helps I can 
explicitly state a few more.

My question is that  if someone claims a formula for $N^d(m,\chi_k)$ 
for some other surface and line bundle, is there a 
similar way to make low degree checks, atleast in some cases?

Let me just define what are $A_k$, $D_k$ and $E_k$ singularities. 
A curve $f(x,y)=0$ has an $A_k$ singularity at the origin 
if it can be expressed after a change of coordinates as 
$$ y^2 + x^{k+1} =0, \qquad A_k.$$
It is of type $D_k$ if it can be expressed as 
$$ y^2 x + x^{k-1} =0, \qquad D_k.$$
There are similar definitions for $E_6$, $E_7$ etc, which I can write down, if it helps.

Here is a related question I have asked as well

[Is P^2 important in Kontsevich's recursion formula?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92349/is-p2-important-in-kontsevichs-recursion-formula)

Comment: Curves in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ are about as easy to write down as curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$.  I also encourage you to look at some of the work of Heather Jean Russell, who thought about very similar problems.

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011214

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing out this reference. 
A second question I had is this: consider Kontsevich's 
recursion formula for the number of rational degree d 
curves (through the right number of points) in P^2. 
Is it possible to modify his proof and 
obtain a similar formula for the number of rational curves in some other surface S? Was P^2 important in Kontsevich's argument in 
a significant way?

Comment: I have asked the question in the previous comment as a separate 
question on mathoverflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92349/is-p2-important-in-kontsevichs-recursion-formula